# Phone verification without authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase has recently  depreciated PhoneAuthprovider.verfiyPhonenumber() , which was used to verify mobile number, instead their documentation asks to use PhoneAuthOptions options() which actually is a method for phone authentication (sign in with user's number). My situation is that I don't want to have phone authentication, rather I just want to verify the users mobile number for my security purposes. Like internet banking , an OTP has to be send to registered mobile if it is verified then moves to next activity. Whether any one can tell me how to do this with current firebase set up..

Comment: That use-case is not supported as far as I know.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ..Earlier that were possible with PhoneAuthprovider.verfiyPhonenumber()